# Initialize value in dictionary only once, then just update

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, .net-core

I'm currently working to track packages when they move between bays, these changes happen every dozen or so seconds, so I have several threads accessing some dictionaries. The idea is that the first few times, I will not have the lastBay value (the program is just starting), but when `A == B` for the first time, I save the value of A (the bay that the pacakage has landed into, therefore the last bay at which it has been) and then just update said value every time `A == B` again.

```
    private void in_bay()
    {
        String line_type = getDictionaryValues("global", "line_type").getStringValue();
        bool result = false;

        switch (line_type)
        {
            case "A_1":
                int A = getVariableFromBucket("A_Act").getIntValue();
                int B = getVariableFromBucket("A_Next").getIntValue();
                result = A == B ? true : false;
                if (result)
                {
                    setDictionaryValues("global", "lastBay", new Variable("UNSIGNED8") { binaryValue = Utils.intToByteArray(A) });
                }
                break;
        }
        setVariableInBucket("IN_BAY", BitConverter.GetBytes(result));

        log("IN_BAY flag in BUCKET: " + getVariableFromBucket("IN_BAY").getBoolValue(), DEBUG);

        if (getDictionaryValues("global", "lastBay").binaryValue != null)
        {
            log("lastBay value in global: " + getDictionaryValues("global", "lastBay").getIntValue(), DEBUG);
        }
        else
        {
            log("undefined bay",DEBUG);
        }
    }
```

I have a getDictionaryValue() function that returns the variables (or an empty one if it's not in the dictionary):

```
    public Variable getDictionaryValues(String DictionaryName, String VarName)
    {
        try
        {
            return functionDictionary[DictionaryName][VarName];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Variable emptyVariable = new Variable()
            {
                additionalInfo = null,
                arrivalTime = 0,
                binaryValue = null,
                numBits = 0,
                signed = false,
                varType = null
            };
            return emptyVariable;
        }
    }
```

and a setDictionaryValue() function that actually sets the values to the dictionary selected:

```
    public void setDictionaryValues(String DictionaryName, String VariableName, Variable VaValue)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (GlobalConstants.filtersLock)
            {
                if (!functionDictionary.ContainsKey(DictionaryName))
                {
                    functionDictionary.Add(DictionaryName, new Dictionary<String, Variable>());
                }

                if (!functionDictionary[DictionaryName].ContainsKey(VariableName))
                {
                    functionDictionary[DictionaryName].Add(VariableName, Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    functionDictionary[DictionaryName][VariableName] = Value;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log("An error has ocurred when setting values to functionDictionary: "+ e,DEBUG);
            throw new Exception(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the first time `A == B` It logs correctly the values being received, but when the values change again (the package starts moving again) the code no longer displays the values of lastBay, as if the dictionary global no longer has a value for lastBay. I attach an image with a reference as to the expected results and the results obtained:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: The question arises why you don't use a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`?

Comment: Your `switch` only has one `case`: what should happen if `line_type` isn't `"A_1"`? Try logging the line_type to see if it's always "A_1". Also, as a general pointer, learn to use the debugger so you can step through the code line by line and see the values of each of the variables. I know that's harder in a multithreaded environment, but I suspect your problem here could be reproduced with a simple, single-threaded unit test.

Comment: (Seeing as all of the keys for the "buckets" and dictionaries are constants, for me the question arises why you're using dictionaries at all?)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Bussiness need, I've argued against them before, but the solution already implements these all around. I've used the debug window to freeze the threads and try with one alone, but even then I can't find the error. and as to the switch, if I change that for a very comprehensive if else statement, I still get the same result

Comment: Is it possible that `functionDictionary` is not the same instance across calls to `in_bay`? Maybe it's a private field, and there are a bunch of different instances of your class?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior You were correct sir! I asked to see the instance where these dictionaries are declared and it didn't have any access modifier, Thank you for the guidance!

Comment: I feel I need to point out that there are _a lot_ of code smells here. I know in some work environments it can be hard to push against existing practices, and I wouldn't want you risking your position or anything, but do what you can to practically push things in the right direction. Research and implement SOLID principles. Drive toward the simplest solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment thread, it looks like the problem is that `in_bay` is being called on different object instances, and `functionDictionary` is a non-static field, so you're dealing with different dictionary instances each time.

I just want to take the opportunity to point out how much simpler your code could be if you just used classes and variables rather than adding dictionaries and "Variable" objects as a layer of abstraction.

```
private void in_bay()
{
    string? line_type = BayState.line_type;
    bool result = false;

    if(line_type == "A_1")
    {
        int A = Bucket.A_Act;
        int B = Bucket.A_Next;
        result = A == B;
        if (result)
        {
            BayState.lastBay = A;
        }
    }

    Bucket.IN_BAY = result;

    log("IN_BAY flag in BUCKET: " + Bucket.IN_BAY, DEBUG);

    if (BayState.lastBay != null)
    {
        log("lastBay value in global: " + BayState.lastBay.Value, DEBUG);
    }
    else
    {
        log("undefined bay", DEBUG);
    }
}
```

I can pretty much guarantee whatever "business need" is driving the desire for dictionaries and such can be accomplished in another way that still allows you to write clean and less error-prone code.